# Understanding headers in scrartcl

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

I would like to get a better understanding, why using `fancyhdr` is not recommended using `scrartcl`. So far I haven't had any problems using them together but the output is always complaining that I shouldn't use `fancyhdr` with `scrartcl`. Instead I should use `scrlayer-scrpage`. Can somebody please explain the reason why I shouldn't use `fancyhdr`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=1cm, bottom=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Name}
\chead{Page \thepage}
\lhead{Title description}

\begin{document}

    \begin{multicols*}{3}
        Some entries here 

        \columnbreak

        and some entries there

        \columnbreak

        and the list goes on 
    \end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Short answer: Both packages try to set the macros responsible for the page headers, but do it differently. It might work, but that's not guaranteed

Comment: The author of KOMA decided that `fancyhdr` is not suitable for KOMA.

Comment: `scrartcl` is part of KOMA-Script as it is `scrpage2` or  `scrlayer-scrpage`.  They work perfect together.  `fancyhdr` is not part of KOMA-Script.  Read the KOMA-Script documentation please (`texdoc KOMA-Script`).

Comment: You lose features of the class. Some things will no longer work. Commands will have no effect or global changes will not do what you think. The class assumes that certain commands are defined in certain ways and it uses that to provide a coherent user interface. **fancyhdr** overwrites some of those commands, so that many features of the class which depend on those commands will no longer work and other commands' cooperation with those commands will be reduced or eliminated.

Comment: @ cfr - thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only use one of the packages `scrlayer-scrpage`, `scrpage2` (predecessor of `scrlayer-scrpage`), `fancyhdr`, ...

The recommended package for use with a KOMA-Script class is `scrlayer-scrpage`because it is part of the KOMA-Script bundle and you can set and change options in the same way as for the class, see the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf). I really suggest to use `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Your header with `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,% default
  %pagesize,% default since version 3.17
  landscape,
  fontsize=6pt,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=1cm, bottom=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{Name}
\chead{\pagemark}
\ihead{Title description}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page\nobreakspace\thepage}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
\Blinddocument
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

---

But using `fancyhdr` is also possible if really want to use this package:

```
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,% default
  %pagesize,% default since version 3.17
  landscape,
  fontsize=6pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=1cm, bottom=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}Name}
\fancyhead[C]{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\pagemark}
\fancyhead[L]{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}Title description}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page\nobreakspace\thepage}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
\Blinddocument
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Note that with `fancyhdr` a small number of options regarding page header and footer will not work. An example is the KOMA option `footsepline`.

So if you really want to use `fancyhdr` and there is **only** the warning that the usage of `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended 
you can ignore it.

---

**But do not ignore any additional warning regarding the old font commands like `\rm`, `\sl`.** Note that `fancyhdr` uses this commands in its default header and footer definitions.

Starting with the [current prerelease of the **next KOMA-Script Version**](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801) (**3.20**) KOMA Script does not define this old commands.  So

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/11/06]
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

will result in errors. You can avoid the errors if you either use `\fancyhf{}` and define your own header and footer using `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` without the usage of old font commands or you use a compatibility option.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer - redefined my headers yesterday with `scrlayer-scrpage` because I actually faced some problems with `fancyhdr` minutes after I wrote this question.

Comment: Thanks, this showed me how to fix up my `fancyhdr` instructions with `\usekomafont`. I tried converting to `scrlayer-scrpage` first, but that package doesn’t support graphics in headlines, so I’m sticking with `fancyhdr` as it WFM.

Comment: @mirabilos Why do you think that `scrlayer-scrpage` does not support graphics in headlines?

Comment: @esdd Because it throws an error in that case. But nevermind, fancyhdr works just okay for me.

Comment: If your code does not use old font commands the usage of  `fancyhdr` with a KOMA Script class is ok too. But if you want to know what goes wrong with your `scrlayer-scrpage` test then ask a new question with a MWE. Maybe we will find the reason of the error message.